# tcl - detect if x11 is running on ARM or x86

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, arm, tcl

I have a tcl script that currently detects its platform by looking at `tk windowingsystem` and then loads different libraries depending on if the result is x11, win32, aqua, etc...

However, this is causing issues on linux - as the libraries for raspberry pi and standard linux are different.

What I'm looking for is a way to differentiate between x11 running on ARM, and x11 running on x86.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Tcl package `platform` sounds ideal:

```
% package require platform
1.0.13
% platform::identify
macosx10.8-x86_64
```